# One wordpress website is always interpreting link to other wordpress site hosted on same VPS as an internal link

Tags: wordpress, ip, hosting, vps, broken-links

So I work on this Wordpress website with an event calendar at work.
Another organization had a problem getting support from their hosting, so we migrated them to our VPS as a temporary solution.
Since that has happened, they've been submitting events to our calendar, with links going to their website.
However, Wordpress upon seeing those links systematically interprets them as internal links, and looks for the document locations within our own domain name and website (and obviously doesn't find them, resulting in broken links).

I was wondering if this issue had to do with Wordpress identifying the IP address of the other site as being local because it's on the same VPS, and then interpreting local as being part of the same site?

If so, how do I have to set up the hosting on the VPS to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in adding links in the WYSIWYG editor, and the fact that they were providing urls in their form entries without the http:// component, and that the link automatically has http:// selected (highlighted in blue), so that if you just paste the links, and they are missing the http:// component, it will look for the url within the current domain.

Not sure if there is a config for that to prevent that hiccup, but a single stroke to the right arrow before pasting has solved everything.